# Java Int(Why returning 0 when number is within range)

Tags: java, integer

Thank you for your time!

1. for value upto 2147483641 code is working fine after that it is returning 0(why)..
   as per my understanding program should return 0 only when overflow occurs.. (for    -2147483648 and 2147483647 ) not for value falling in the range.
2. Also please share any link for leading zero number reversal.. I could not find any  online.

   ```
    public class ReverseDigit {
        public int reverse(int integer) {
            boolean negflag=false;
            if(integer<0){
                      negflag=true;
                      integer=integer*-1;
                          }
            int rev=0;
            int rem=0;
            while(integer!=0){
                     rem=integer%10;
                     int newrev= rev*10+rem;
                     if((newrev-rem)/10!=rev){
                     return 0;
                                              }
             else{

                     rev=newrev;
                 }
                     integer=integer/10;
        }
                      return  rev = negflag?rev*-1:rev;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
                ReverseDigit rd = new ReverseDigit();
                System.out.println(rd.reverse(**2147483642**));


    }
   ```

   }

Comment: Reverse for `2147483642` is `2463847412` which is greater than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, hence the code returns zero.

Comment: oh I am so sorry! such a silly thing... Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happens because the reversed number of `2147483642` is `2463847412`, and this number is greater then `Intrgre.MAX_VALUE` which is `2147483647`, so the number became less than 0.
This is happens to `2147483623` too, because his reversed number is `3263847412`, and this number is greater then `Intrgre.MAX_VALUE`.
To fix that, I see two possible solutions:

1. Use `long` instead of `int`.
2. Rewrite the method to work with `String`, because you aren't really do any calculations (You can use `string.charAt(int index)` to get the digits one bt one).